# Значение мультиселекта поумолчанию

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

Использую bootstrap multiselect в форме, необходимо подставлять в мультиселект значения из адресной строки. Для передачи одного значения использовал такую конструкцию:

```
<?php
$value = \Yii::$app->request->get($name) ?: '';
?>

<div class="<?= $class ? $class : "col-sm-3 col-xs-12" ?>">
    <label><?= $label ?></label>
    <select name="<?= $name ?>" multiple="multiple">
        <?php foreach ($source as $id => $val) { ?>
            <option <?= $value == $id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="<?= $id ?>"><?= $val ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Теперь же передаётся массив, как реализовать подстановку всех значений массива?

Comment: как выглядит массив в адресной строке?

Comment: &multiselect_region[]=417899&multiselect_region[]=407436&multiselect_region[]=357975
Один из примеров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
<?php
$values = \Yii::$app->request->get($name) ?: [];
?>

<div class="<?= $class ? $class : "col-sm-3 col-xs-12" ?>">
    <label><?= $label ?></label>
    <select name="<?= $name ?>" multiple="multiple">
        <?php foreach ($source as $id => $val) { ?>
            <option <?= in_array($id, $values) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="<?= $id ?>"><?= $val ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало, ничего не произошло, print_r($values) ничего не вывело.

Comment: $name указали `multiselect_region`? или со скобками в конце? нужно только имя указать

Comment: Да, дурной не подумал, что в $name подставляется как раз со скобками, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще использовать `yii\helpers\Html`:

`Html::dropDownList($name', $values, $source, ['multiple' => true])`